# Можно ли в JavaScript отследить нажатие на кнопку Reload?

Tags: javascript

Можно ли в JavaScript отследить нажатие на кнопку Reload? Проблема в том что она вне окна страницы

Comment: Нет. Нельзя....

Comment: можно в общем контексте покидания страницы, только сделать можно только синхронную операцию, например записать localstorage - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onbeforeunload

Comment: Нажатие кнопок на панели инструментов браузера, из скрипта на странице отследить конечно невозможно - а обновление/перезагрузку страницы определить можно несколькими способами (например, используя [свойство `type` объекта интерфейса `PerformanceNavigationTiming`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/PerformanceNavigationTiming/type) - сейчас поддерживается большинством браузеров, кроме IE и Safari).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам нужно отловить событие перезагрузки страницы как я понял (т.е. по сути кнопка reload это и делает - перезагружает страницу). можем обратиться к window.performance

```
if (window.performance) {
 console.info("window.performance works fine on this browser");
}
console.info(performance.navigation.type);
if (performance.navigation.type == 
  performance.navigation.TYPE_RELOAD) {
  console.info( "This page is reloaded" );
} else {
  console.info( "This page is not reloaded");
}
```

Comment: Хорошо бы [источник копипаста](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36444134/12506088) указывать в знак уважения к автору оригинального кода/ответа.

Comment: код проверен и работает

Comment: Ок, второе замечание снимается :)